# ifconfig up for multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, bash, ifconfig

I want to execute "up" command for multiple interfaces and thought that using ifconfig eth{0..3} up would help, it doesn't, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *for loop* e.g.

```
for i in {0..3}; do ifconfig eth${i} up; done
```